# PyCups Failed building wheel for pycups on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cups, pycups

I'm trying to install pycups on my raspberry pi running Python 2.7.16 and pip version 18.1. I'm trying to install with the following command:

```
sudo pip install pycups
```

But it keeps failing and giving this error:

```
Failed building wheel for pycups
Running setup.py clean for pycups
Failed to build pycups
```

Any ideas what could be wrong and how I can install pycups on my Pi?

I've tried

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

And both say they are up-to-date

Comment: Have you find the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Given that Python 2 reached it's end of life in 2020/01/01, pycups 2.0 and later require Python 3.

If you already have Python 3 installed, you may run the command as

```
pip3 install pycups
```

The same applies to `python`, becoming `python3` to disambiguate.

Note that the dependencies also change:

```
sudo apt install gcc python3-dev libcups2-dev
```

Comment: `libcups2-dev` was the missing dependency for me. Works on a Pi Zero with all three dependencies.